# Regex for telephone numbers with specific prefixes

Tags: regex, numbers

I'm created this regex to match telephone numbers that have three specific prefixes, but it's not perfect. I need a regex that will only match numbers with the prefixes `+48`, `+420`, `421` and nothing else.

```
^[+][4](8|2)[0-9]{1,14}\d
```

When the Input is `+421 456 456 456ioejkfoi312` I want the regular expression to match `+421 456 456 456`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works perfectly.

```js
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+48123")) // true
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+420 123")) // true
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+421 12 3")) // true
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+422123")) // false
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+41123")) // false
console.log(/\+420\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|\+421\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}|48\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}\s*\d{1,5}/.test("+421456456456")) // true
```

Anything else gives false

Comment: I'm using this site to check and it's not working for all number. Only for prefix. https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Check now, I tried it, on the same site and its working for this text: +421 456 456 456ioejkfoi312